# Remove white spaces before and after an image

Tags: r, knitr, rnw

I set `echo = false` in .Rnw file with knitr. The output is a graph with lots of white space around it. How do I decrease the white space so that the graph is not too far away from the main text?

Comment: You mean extra white space inside of the plot (see eg `par(mar = rep(0, 4))`) or around the image?

Comment: @daroczig around the image

Comment: Then I think it depends on your output format, and you need to tweak eg CSS when it comes to HTML.